# I m reading a csv file using pandas in jupyter notebook which is on desktop but throws following error:File wine.csv does not exist

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I m reading a csv file using `pandas` in Jupyter notebook which is on desktop but throws following error:

```
IOError: File wine.csv does not exist
```

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("wine.csv")
```

And the file `wine.csv` is on desktop and sometimes it import it and sometimes it doesn't with same code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `pwd` command on your jupyter notebook?

You said that the file `wine.csv` is present on the desktop. But unless your notebook is also launched from the same directory as the directory where `wine.csv` is present.

You won't be able to find it using relative paths.

Use the fully qualified path name.

eg - `/home/Desktop/wine.csv`

or start your notebook is the same directory as your `wine.csv` file